# Spring Websocket doesn't listen to Unsubscribe event with @stomp/stompjs

Tags: spring-websocket, stompjs

I have a spring websocket project and created a very basic page to test it and everything seems to work fine, with the exception of the listener for the UNSUBSCRIBE message.

```
    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionSubscribeEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBED " + event);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionUnsubscribeEvent(SessionUnsubscribeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("UNSUBSCRIBED " + event);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleSessionDisconnectEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        System.out.println("DISCONNECTED " + event);
    }
```

When the frontend makes the subscription, I get the first print from the listener, but when it unsubscribes the listener is not triggered.
You can see on Chrome's websocket log that the UNSUBSCRIBE message was sent:

```
["CONNECTED\nversion:1.1\nheart-beat:0,0\nuser-name:BsFJQRRyrKR4iUdSZyx0\n\n\u0000"]
["SUBSCRIBE\nid:666\ndestination:/topic/myTopic\n\n\u0000"]
["MESSAGE\ndestination:/topic/myTopic\ncontent-type:application/json\nsubscription:666\nmessage-id:hfxgxgci-4\ncontent-length:57\n\n{\"timestamp\":\"2021-08-04T14:34:22.157688Z\",\"value\":239.0}\u0000"]
["MESSAGE\ndestination:/topic/myTopic\ncontent-type:application/json\nsubscription:666\nmessage-id:hfxgxgci-4\ncontent-length:57\n\n{\"timestamp\":\"2021-08-04T14:34:22.157688Z\",\"value\":474.0}\u0000"]
["MESSAGE\ndestination:/topic/myTopic\ncontent-type:application/json\nsubscription:666\nmessage-id:hfxgxgci-4\ncontent-length:57\n\n{\"timestamp\":\"2021-08-04T14:34:22.157688Z\",\"value\":120.0}\u0000"]
["UNSUBSCRIBE\nid:666\n\n\u0000"]
```

This is my code in the frontend for the subscription:

`` const subscription = await WebSocketService.subscribe(`/topic/myTopic`); ``

An this is my code for the unsubscription:

```
return () => {
    batcher.clear();

    subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
};
```

As you can see from the Chrome log, the UNSUBSCRIBE message is being sent, but my listener doesn't trigger.
Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm just experiencing the same problem. Could you solve it somehow?

Comment: @Walnussbär I "solved".
In fact it wasn't really a bug, the problem was caused because during the SUBSCRIBE, I was doing a rest call, and when I had around 1000 subscribers subscribing at the same time, it took a while for all the subscriptions to finish, and the problem was being caused when a subscription that was not yet finished tried to UNSUBSCRIBE.

Try to make a test with only 1 subscription, it should work.